Powershell script is not efficient
Hi My PowerShell script below is basically doing a find/replace in a log file. It runs OK on smaller files but on large logs files it takes a long time and uses a lot of memory. I'm looking for alternative way to do this:
(Get-Content -Path D:\path\error.log) |
ForEach-Object {$_ -Replace '(?<=password\=)(.*)(?=.$)', 'secret'} |
Set-Content -Path D:\path\error.log 

The script gets the contents of the file then does the regex find /replace and saves it back.
When log files get over 100mb the script becomes very slow to complete and it uses a lot of the system memory on the host machine.

Memory consumption will be high because you want to overwrite the file content instead of writing to a new file however, you can make your code more efficient by using -Raw to read the content as a single multi-line string:
(Get-Content -Path D:\path\error.log -Raw) -replace '(?m)(?<=password\=).*(?=.$)', 'secret' |
    Set-Content -Path D:\path\error.log

It's probable that you also don't need the look-ahead ((?=.$)):
(Get-Content -Path D:\path\error.log -Raw) -replace '(?<=password\=).*', 'secret' |
    Set-Content -Path D:\path\error.log


That worked a treat so thanks for the tip. The look ahead is something I can remove, historically it was more complicated regex but the logging has been adapted so the lookahead is no longer needed.
